# decoding json from mysql database and displaying it on a table php

Tags: php, mysql

I encoded some values which i stored in mysql database. I want to decode them to display on a table using PHP.

**Sample query i am using:**

```
$sql = "SELECT `coc_id`, `cc_id`, `category_options`FROM 
`ag_category_option_combos` WHERE coc_id='831'";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
# code...
// $data = array();
$data = json_decode($row['category_options'], true);

echo '  <tr>
            <td>' . $row['coc_id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['cc_id'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $data['id'] .'</td>
            <td>' . $data['name'] .'</td>
        </tr>';

print_r($data);
echo $data;
}
```

**sample mysql data in the database:**

```
  ----+---------------------+------------+                                                                                
  | coc_id | cc_id | category_options  | created_at          | updated_at |                                                                                
   +--------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------+                                                                                
  |     16 |    15 | {"categoryOption":{"id":"13","name":"default"}} | 2018-03-19 09:42:06 |            |                                                                                
  |    825 |   824 | {"categoryOption":[{"id":"798","name":"<15"},
  {"id":"821","name":"Male"}]}  | 2018-03-19 09:42:06 |            |                                                                                
  |    826 |   824 | {"categoryOption":[{"id":"798","name":"<15"},{"id":"822","name":"Female"}]}       | 2018-03-19 09:42:06 |            |                                                                                
  |    827 |   824 | {"categoryOption":[{"id":"799","name":"15 - 24"},{"id":"821","name":"Male"}]}            | 2018-03-19 09:42:06 |            |                                                                                
  |    828 |   824 | {"categoryOption":[{"id":"799","name":"15 - 24"},{"id":"822","name":"Female"}]}           | 2018-03-19 09:42:06 |            |                                                                                
  |    829 |   824 | {"categoryOption":[{"id":"800","name":"25 - 34"},{"id":"821","name":"Male"}]}           | 2018-03-19 09:42:06 |            |                                                                                
  |    830 |   824 | {"categoryOption":[{"id":"800","name":"25 - 34"},{"id":"822","name":"Female"}]}                          | 2018-03-19 09:42:06 |            |
```

what i want now is on each row it display all items on columns coc_id and cc_id but one array of values from category_options and the other one array to be on the next row

Example: **Using row 2 from the sample mysql data above**

```
 <tr>
   <td>825</td>
   <td>824</td>
   <td>798</td>
   <td><15</td>
 </tr>

   <tr>
     <td>825</td>
     <td>824</td>
     <td>821</td>
     <td>Male</td>
   </tr>
```

How do i get to do this??
Or if there is a better way to do so please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over all elements in your JSON, to repeat the `<tr>` tag:

```
$data = json_decode($row['category_options'], true);

// Fix if $data['categoryOption'] is not an "array" of elements
if (isset($data['categoryOption']['id'])) {
    $data['categoryOption'] = [$data['categoryOption']];
}

// loop over $data['categoryOption'] array of the JSON:
foreach ($data['categoryOption'] as $item) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $row['coc_id'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $row['cc_id'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $item['id'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $item['name'] .'</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: hi, for columns with a single array, like on row 1: ` {"categoryOption":{"id":"13","name":"default"}}` how do you go about for them, because on such rows it echos: `PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\reports-agpahi\view.php on line 23
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\reports-agpahi\view.php on line 24` and only shows the first character/letter from the string: `<tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>`

Comment: @EmilKitua I've updated the answer. See the `if` before the loop.